# Почему приходится явно указывать простанство имён при для System.Random?

Tags: c#, массивы, случайные-числа

Почему в работе со ступенчатым массивом при вызове генератора случайных чисел нужно указать namespace System?
А в работе с прямоугольным - не нужно?

Код:

```
using System;

namespace Random
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] myArray = new int[3][];
            myArray[0] = new int[5];
            myArray[1] = new int[2]; 
            myArray[2] = new int[10]; 
            System.Random random = new System.Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    myArray[i][j] = random.Next(100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите код. Пространства имён работают не так, скорее всего вам просто не хватает `using System`.

Comment: Быть может у вас есть свой класс или переменная с именем `System`, и она конфликтует с пространством имен. Не посмотрев ваш код это определить невозможно.

Comment: @aepot using System;

namespace Random
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] myArray = new int[3][];
            myArray[0] = new int[5];
            myArray[1] = new int[2];
            myArray[2] = new int[10];

            System.Random random = new System.Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    myArray[i][j] = random.Next(100);
                }
            }

Comment: @Георгий не надо в комментарий, надо вопрос, отредактируйте его. Но я уже вижу - ваше приложение называется `Random` - `namespace Random`, это конфликтует с классом `Random`. Переименуйте пространство имен своего приложения.